# Hiding Hyper V Virtualization

Tags: windows-10, virtual-machine, cpu, virtualization, hyper-v

I’m new to using hyper V and I have a windows 10 host os to windows 10 guest os.

For hiding the virtualization in VMware we can add `hypervisor.cpuid.v0 = false` and the cpu does not get shown as a  virtualization.

Is there any powershell or setting command that can do the same for hyper v?

I have tried `Set-VMProcessor -VMName <VMName> -ExposeVirtualizationExtensions $true`  and virtualization still gets shown with task manger saying `Virtualization: Yes`

Comment: Did you actually set `ExposeVirtualizationExtensions` to *true* or is that a mistake in the question?

Comment: @DanielB I did set it to true even tested it with: (Get-VMProcessor
-VMName <VMName>) .ExposeVirtualizationExtensions and it came back as true

Comment: That's the opposite of what you want. You do not want to *expose* them, you want to *hide* them.

Comment: @DanielB That's true, but hypervisor cuid is used for nested vms in VMware so I wanted to and find the equivalent of that here incase it worked the same way.